# Get open popup windows in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing my first Google Chrome extension.

Let's say I'm on http://example.com and there's a popup window from http://example.net open.

Is there a way to get the http://example.net popup reference when I click the browserAction button from the http://example.com page?

Comment: [chrome.extension.getViews](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getViews)

Comment: is example.net your popup (from your extension) or popupu made by example.com page?... if later, on button click use [chrome.windows.getAll](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll)  and set filter to popup. This will get you ALL (possible) popups. You can then run trough them and test if url domain is the same like the one on clicked tab.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getAll()` method from [chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getAll).

```
chrome.windows.getAll(object getInfo, function callback)
```